[Spring Boot][REST] Design Pattern Best Practice (Single Entity, multiple business logic implementations)
I have some problems regarding best-practice design between data source layer(Entity), domain layer(Service) and presentation layer (controller):
I have one entity with a type field in the database to distinguish between two subtypes(Burger and Pizza), because they share most attributes and act similarly
Let's say, the only difference is, Burger has attribute "layer number", Pizza has an attribute "Diameter" and their cook() methods have different implementations.
So my Idea is: I use single big table that accomodates both types, intentionally leaving some unused fields empty.
Example of Table RECIPE:



id
name
type
diameter
layerNumber
status




1
VegiBurger
BURGER
null
1
DONE


2
ChickenBurger
BURGER
null
3
WAIT


3
Pizza Mozzarella
PIZZA
10
null
DONE



Now comes the problem:
I’ve moved the cook() logic into a wrapper class, RecipeCooker, because business logic should not be in Entity class.
However, this means I now have two versions of cook() for both Recipe types, depending on the type field.
My Question: Is this a bad pattern? How would you improve this design that follows SOLID principle/dev best practices?
This is my data source layer: (entities should not contain business logics)
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    // properties for the recipe
    private String id;
    private RecipeType type;  // Can be BURGER or PIZZA
    private RecipeStatus status;
    // Other fields specific to a Recipe
}

This is my Controller (presentation layer)
 // POST methods to create a recipe and cook it
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Recipe createRecipe(@RequestBody @Valid Recipe recipe) {
        return recipeService.createRecipe(recipe);
    }

    @PostMapping("/{recipeId}/cook")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void cookRecipe(@PathVariable String recipeId) {
        recipeService.cookRecipe(recipeId);
    }

//Business logics are here, but this method cook() is now tightly coupled with two implementations of Recipe subtypes
public class RecipeCooker {
    private final Recipe recipe;
    private final RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    public RecipeCooker(Recipe recipe,
                                RecipeRepository recipeRepository) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
        this.recipeRepository = recipeRepository;
    }


//THIS IS PROBABLY BAD DESIGN, BUT I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO IMPROVE.
    @Override
    public String cook() throws Exception {
        switch (recipe.getType()) {
            case BURGER:
                return cookBurger();
            case PIZZA:
                return cookPizza();
            default:
                throw new RecipeTypeNotExistException("Invalid recipe type: " + recipe.getType());
        }
    }

    // Method for cooking Burger 
    private String cookBurger(){...}

    // Method for cooking Pizza
    private String cookPizza(){...}

}


So you have an entity, a table in the DB with a couple of entries that corresponds to it. But then things become unclear. Can you, please, edit the question and specify the responsibilities of RecipeCooker. What is the responsibility of the method cook() and why delegates to 3 different methods? Where you're using this method? How recipeService and RecipeCooker relate to each other? What is the expected outcome of cookRecipe()? Since it's POST-request, then it probably changes something?

This would be off topic for two reasons: it's hypothetical code and incomplete (classes missing).

I see problems in data and business layers:
Data Layer
the design of the DB table is not normalized. if in future, more recipees are added with specific attributes, you would have to add more nullable columns to your table. there are two possible soluitions:

table RECIPEE should have only the common attributes for all recipees. create additional tables to hold recipee-specific attributes, with foreigh key to point to RECIPEE. for example, table BURGER_RECIPEE:




id
recipee_id
layerNumber




1
1
1


2
2
3



you can fetch the recipee for vegi burger using join in the query

a more general aproach would be to create a key-value table to hold all recipee-specific attributes:




id
recipee_id
att_name
att_value




1
1
layerNumber
1


2
2
layerNumber
3


3
3
diameter
10



in this case, the java entity for the attributes would probably be a Map<String, Integer> or perhaps Map<String, Object> but it will still hold attributes for requested recipee because of join condition
Service Layer
indeed, cook() method with switch on recipee type is bad design. this calls for polymorphic solution:

identify a common signature for cooking methods and put in an interface. perhaps something like

public interface Cooker {
    String cook(Recipee recipeeEntity, Map<String, Integer> attributes);
}

(however, I would expect the data layer to combine recipeeEntity and attributes into one dto, since the separation is DB implementation detail).
the interface can also be an abstract super class that holds common processing for all recipees (error handling?)

create required implemetations for the interface per recipee:

public class BurgerCooker implements Cooker {
    @Override 
    public String cook(Recipee recipeeEntity, Map<String, Integer> attributes) {
        // ...
    }
}


now you just need to associate recipee type with the relevant cooker implementation. I suggest to add property to the RecipeType enum

@Getter
public enum RecipeType {
    BURGER(new BurgerCooker()) ,

    private Cooker cooker;

    RecipeType(Cooker cooker) {
        this.cooker = cooker;
    }
}

this gives direct access to cooking method from recipee type: recipe.getType().getCooker().cook(...)
the only problem with this solution, is that the cooker implementations are not instantiated using Spring injection mechanism. if indeed you need to autowire cooker implementations (perhaps the cookers need access to other injected services) than you can add setters to the enum and populate the cooker property in post construct.

For data layer, I also considered the first approach you mentioned:
I think this is called "Joined Table Inheritance".
How would the Restcontroller look like? Does client specify the Recipe type in query parameter, in RequestBody or should I have separate endpoints for every Recipe types I have?

the data layer design should not influence the design of REST api. the repository in the data layer should be able to get a recipee dto or recipee type and attrs , build the entities and save to db

But how does the recipeService.create() return the correct type if we only uses one endpoint ? I guess one solution is to pass the requested type(burger, pizza) as string in the query parameter?
@PostMapping("/")
public Recipe createRecipe(... type) {
return recipeService.createRecipe(recipe, type);
}

regardless of the design of service/data layer, the service should get the required type in arg. indeed i see recipeeService.create gets an instance of Recipee as arg. the dto should have type attribute. the last code line in my answer recipe.getType().getCooker().cook(...) uses the same variable that is used by the switch statement
